# Some changes missing in Changelog?

Tags: support

Where is the complete Changelog for StackExchange sites? I thought it is this: [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

But today I've noticed 2 changes, none of which is on the list:

- Taxonomist badge is no longer bronze, but silver
- I have 50 votes for suggested edits, not 40.

Comment: As far as I can see, Taxonomist [was always silver](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/68258/1) what make you think it was bronze?

Comment: You are probably right, Wizard, thanks! OK, thanks to you and @Daniel, there is no "uknown date" change now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answers to that question are the closest we have to a changelog. It's maintained by us, the community, not Stack Exchange, so if you see something missing please edit it in.

If you can find a reference and/or date for the change so much the better, but if not still edit it in. Someone else *will* be able to provide a reference later (if one exists).

Comment: OK Chris, I've created new group "Unknown date" and added these two. Hope somebody will be able to sort them in. Thanks.

Comment: @Tomas Done the suggested edit change, was on Friday.

Comment: Actually, "It is jointly maintained by the community and Rebecca Chernoff (a Stack Exchange, Inc team member)."

Comment: @PopularDemand - My mistake - feel free to correct it.

Comment: I almost did, but after posting the comment I decided to verify, and it looks like rchern hasn't touched that list since September 2011.